# About the conception of the Bhagwad Gita

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita

If there was no war in Mahabharata, there would be no Bhagwad Gita. Since Bhagwad Gita is a good thing born out of something bad (the war), should we be thankful that the Mahabharata war took place?

Comment: Actually one of the answers and some of the comments in above thread answers your question *indirectly*.  Bhagvad Gita is something being shared multiple times and Mahabharata war is most famous instance of that. Hence if not Mahabharata, it would have come by some other means if it had to. Besides this, there is other dimension to your question. During Mahabharata, the sin on earth had increased (according to then standards), the war happened as a way to flush all the sinners at once. If there were no sinners, then war was not required. In such case Gita would have chosen other route or time.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda has said that it is not necessary to believe that an actual war took place, that the battlefield of the Gita can be taken as an analogy of the fight in each one of us between good and evil tendencies.

Answer (score 0):

B.Gita came because of confusion to Arjuna between Dharma and Karma one has to perform. So even if war would not taken place, gita would have come through some other means. Because all these confusions are occured in day to day life. Its not just in battlefield, but in offices and personal life too. Moreover our internal life too has wars between good and bad.

Also to note here is that Krishna gave not just B.Gita but so many other gitas like Uddhava Gita which did gave during peace time to Uddhava (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamsa_Gita).